# IEで window.location.href に data:text/csv;... を設定することが出来ない

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

現在、tableをCSV出力するために[table2CSV.jquery](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php)を使用しています。
IE(ver11)の場合、下記のソース中のencodeURIComponentを window.location.hrefに代入している部分でエラーになっており、エラーメッセージは特にないです。※chromeは動作確認済み
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうにか動作するようにしたいのですが、
IEで動作させるための方法が分る方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

```js
 var csv = $("#example").table2CSV({ delivery: 'file' });
    window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,'
                          + encodeURIComponent(csv);
```

Comment: どの様なエラーか書かないと回答が貰いづらいと思います。

Comment: エラー時の画像を載せました。
画像の通り、エラー内容は出力されておらず、原因が分らない状況です

Comment: encodeURIComponent ではなく、location.href への代入でエラーが出ているんじゃないでしょうか？一度 encodeURIComponent(csv) だけで実行すると確認出来ます。おそらくですが、IE では画像以外の data scheme は制限があるんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: encodeURIComponentだけで実行出来ることを確認することが出来ました。
data scheme の制限とは、例えばどのような制限のことを示しているのでしょうか。

Comment: IE8/IE9 の頃は data scheme は画像しか使えませんでした。その後 IE10/IE11 でどうなったかは確認していませんが。

Comment: 理解することが出来ました。ありがとうございます。
おそらくIE10/IE11 でも動作しないようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

解決することが出来ました

・IE

```
var csv = $("#example").table2CSV({ delivery: 'value' });
var blobObject = new Blob([csv]);
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'data.csv');
```

・Chrome safari

```
$('#example').tableExport({ type: 'csv', escape: 'false' });
```

Comment: Blob のコンストラクタの第二引数に `{ type: "text/csv" }` を入れた方が良いです。`new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" })`

Comment: ありがとうございます、了解しました。修正をします。

Comment: 上記の実装で、エンコードがUTF8になっているのですが、shift-jisに変更することは出来ますでしょうか？

Comment: バイト列を得て utf-8 から Shift_JIS に変換する処理が必要になります。探すといろいろある様です。 https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=javascript+utf-8+shift_jis

Answer (score 3):

[data Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710206(v=vs.85).aspx)には

> - object (images only)
> - img
> - input type=image
> - link
> - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background, backgroundImage, and so on.

だけで使用可能と書かれています。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。やはりCSVの出力は許可されていないようですね。
CSVを出力することが出来る実装方法はあるのでしょうか？